# Proof of reflexive property of equality. Is it correct?

Tags: proof-verification

We can assume that for every $a, a=x$, in which $x$ is anything including nothing or something. If $a\neq x$ then $a$ doesn't exist.

$a=x$ given

$x=a$ symmetry

$a=a$ transitive

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Reflexive means $a=a$ for all $a$

Comment: So you are so that for any $a$ such and $\sqrt 5$ and $27$ and $-3$ then $a = x$ where $x$ can be anything including $19$ or $57$. Superman's Underwear.  SO if $42 \ne \sqrt{-59}$ that can only happen if $42$ does not exist..... Are you *sure* this is what you want to claim?

Comment: Reflexive:  Means for all $a$ then $a=a$.   Symmetric:  Means whenever $a=b$ then $b =a$.  And Transitive: means whenever $a=b$ and $b=c$ then $a =c$.  .... what you wrote "We can assume that for every a, a=x, in which x is anything including nothing or something. If a≠x then a doesn't exist" makes utterly zero sense.